# Is there an easy way to prove the matrix $(XYZ)^{-1} = Z^{-1}Y^{-1}X^{-1}$?

Tags: matrices

I've been using pro numerals to show this relationship, and it is taking ages to complete because of all the steps necessary! Any other easier way to prove this statement?

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: If you find an inverse, then it must be unique. Can you prove that $Z^{-1}Y ^{-1}X^{-1}$ times XYZ (in the right and on the left) is 1?

Comment: Multiply xyz(z’y’x’)=1 and since the inverse is unique so that’s it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the relation $(XY)^{-1}=Y^{-1}X^{-1}$ one at a time.
$$(XYZ)^{-1}=((XY)Z)^{-1}=Z^{-1}(XY)^{-1}=Z^{-1}Y^{-1}X^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $(XYZ)^{-1}$ is the *unique* matrix such that 
$$(XYZ)(XYZ)^{-1} = I$$
but also
$$(XYZ)(Z^{-1}Y^{-1}X^{-1}) = (XY)(Y^{-1}X^{-1}) = XX^{-1} = I$$
So, $(XYZ)^{-1} = (Z^{-1}Y^{-1}X^{-1})$.